# PyQt QCalendarWidget — метод не возвращает значение

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyqt4

Есть метод `getCurrentDate` – он должен возвращать значение месяца текущего экрана:

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtGui.QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QCalendarWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('currentPageChanged(int, int)'), self.getCurrentDate)

    def getCurrentDate(self):
        return self.monthShown()

    def out(self):
        print self.getCurrentDate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    gui.show()
    # print:
    gui.out()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Когда я вызываю getCurrentDate, он возвращает текущее значение (e.g. 2 ), однако при смене экрана, метод ничего не возвращает. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки нет, просто вы были невнимательными. При смене страниц слот вызывается.

Вы, наверное, хотели чтобы было написано так: `self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('currentPageChanged(int, int)'),` **self.out**`)`, тогда при смене страниц будет в консоль писаться номер месяца.